# Como ordenar uma query em Django ignorando acentos?

Tags: django, django-1.8

Estou retornando a query `Carro.objects.all().order_by(Lower('marca'))`, mas a ordem não está respeitando nomes que iniciam com acento, fazendo com que esses resultados apareçam no final da ordenação. Existe alguma função que consiga ignorar acentos na hora de ordenar os resultados? Algo como `unaccent` na hora da filtragem que está disponível no Django 1.8.

Answer (score 1):

Não posso falar sobre as versões recentes do Django, mas no último sistema que desenvolvi (acho que era 1.4 ou 1.5) eu não havia encontrado nada, e acabei usando esse *workaround*:

1. Atribua o `locale` da aplicação. A forma de fazer isso é ligeiramente diferente no Unix e no Linux/Windows, então eu terminei com o seguinte código:

   ```
   locale_set_correctly = False
   try:
       locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "pt_BR.UTF-8") # Unix
       locale_set_correctly = True
   except:
       try:
           locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "Portuguese_Brazil.1252") # Linux
           locale_set_correctly = True
       except:
           try:
               locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "") # Tenta usar o locale padrão
               locale_set_correctly = True
           except:
               pass
   ```
2. Leia os registros do banco e depois ordene. Se você pretende usar `all`, não há problema, mas se você gostaria digamos dos `100` primeiros em ordem alfabética, então infelizmente essa opção não serve para você.

   ```
   def locale_sort(result, field):
       if locale_set_correctly:
           def collation(a,b):
               if hasattr(a,field):
                   if hasattr(b,field):
                       fa = getattr(a,field)
                       fb = getattr(b,field)
                       return locale.strcoll(fa, fb)
                   else:
                       return -1
               elif hasattr(b,field):
                   return 1
               else:
                   return -1 if a.pk < b.pk else 1 if b.pk < a.pk else 0
           result.sort(collation)
       return result
   ```

   Usa assim (ordenando primeiro da forma "burra" caso o *locale* não tenha sido atribuído corretamente):

   ```
   resultado = locale_sort(list(Carro.objects.all().order_by(Lower('marca'))), 'marca')
   ```

O [`locale.strcoll`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html#locale.strcoll) vai ordenar de modo que todas as variações da mesma letra (maiúsculas, minúsculas, com acento, sem acento) fiquem juntas na ordenação. Somente se o resto todo for igual, só a letra for diferente, é que ele ordena na ordem `minúscula sem acento < maiúscula sem acento < minúscula com acento < maiúscula com acento`. Exemplo:

```
>>> sorted([u"Alberto", u"Álvaro", u"avião", u"águia"], cmp=locale.strcoll)
[u'\xe1guia', u'Alberto', u'\xc1lvaro', u'avi\xe3o']
>>> sorted([u"A", u"Á", u"a", u"á"], cmp=locale.strcoll)
[u'a', u'A', u'\xe1', u'\xc1']
```

Nota: essa é uma solução bem "robusta", que eu venho usando na prática. Se você tem certeza que o *locale* será suportado, e todos os seus objetos sempre têm o atributo `marca`, você pode simplificar esse código para:

```
resultado = sorted(Carro.objects.all(), cmp=lambda a,b: locale.strcoll(a.marca, b.marca))
```